# xsl/xml div class depends of value

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XSL XML. I get file to work on.
This is template file, later will be transform with xml.
I need to setup class of div depends of value from xml.
I try to get something like this but this not working as I need to close tags...

```
<header class="container-fluid">
    <form>
        <xsl:if test="$CommDelphiBandText = 'Very Low Risk'">
            <div class="green_bg row">
        </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$CommDelphiBandText = 'High Risk'">
                <div class="orange_bg row"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$CommDelphiBandText = 'Maximum risk'">
            <div class="red_bg row"/>
            </xsl:if> 
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Company Name:</label>
                            <div class="">
                                <xsl:value-of select="//a:CommercialName/text()" />
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Registred Number:</label>
                        <div class="">
                            <xsl:value-of select="//a:RegNumber/text()" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
</header>
```

Whole Idea is to change row class as colour will be depend of value of field $CommDelphiBandText in xml.

If I miss any info please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to output a different start tag, try outputting a different `class` attribute.

Also, instead of multiple `xsl:if` which will all be evaluated every time, use `xsl:choose` instead.

Example...

```
<header class="container-fluid">
  <form>
    <div>
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$CommDelphiBandText = 'Very Low Risk'">green_bg row</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$CommDelphiBandText = 'High Risk'">orange_bg row</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$CommDelphiBandText = 'Maximum risk'">red_gb row</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Company Name:</label>
          <div class="">
            <xsl:value-of select="//a:CommercialName/text()"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Registred Number:</label>
          <div class="">
            <xsl:value-of select="//a:RegNumber/text()"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</header>
```